# Force Create record does not prefill account Name field

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I use the force:create:record event to start account creation from my custom component. In the event I prefill some values (code sample below) and this is going fine, except for the "Name" field => this is not being mapped, although it's filled in correctly.

```
createBusinessAccount: function(component, event, helper) {
        var event = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        var businessRecord = component.get("v.businessRecord");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(businessRecord));
        event.setParams({
            "entityApiName": "Account",
            "defaultFieldValues": {
                'RecordTypeId': component.get('v.BusinessAccountRT'),
                'Name': businessRecord.Name,
                'BillingPostalCode': businessRecord.BillingPostalCode,
                'Phone': businessRecord.Phone,
                'VAT_Number__c':businessRecord.VAT_Number__c
            }
        });
        event.fire();
    },
```

Any ideas?

FYI the same works for other objects, so it really seems to be related to accounts. (Same code, other event params)

```
event.setParams({
            "entityApiName": "Opportunity",
            "defaultFieldValues": {
                'RecordTypeId': '012w0000000MRpA',
                'Name': businessRecord.Name
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you please keep a debug point on event.fire(); line and share the debug results or a screenshot of event object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
event.setParams({
    "entityApiName": "Account",
    "recordTypeId": component.get('v.BusinessAccountRT'),
    "defaultFieldValues": {
        'Name': businessRecord.Name,
        'BillingPostalCode': businessRecord.BillingPostalCode,
        'Phone': businessRecord.Phone,
        'VAT_Number__c':businessRecord.VAT_Number__c
    }
});
```

Above code resolved it. => adding recordTypeId in event params.